# SQL query returns value in SSMS, value is DBNull in DataTable

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have this query that I crafted in SQL Server Management Studio to get the definition of a stored procedure in a database.

```
Select [definition], [uses_ansi_nulls], [uses_quoted_identifier], 
    [is_schema_bound], [uses_database_collation], [is_recompiled], 
    [null_on_null_input], [execute_as_principal_id], 
    [uses_native_compilation]
From [sys].[sql_modules]
Where [object_id] = @object_Id
```

In SSMS, if I `Declare @object_Id int = <storedproc's object_id>` and run it, I get back the definition value (the SQL code) and the various other attributes.

In my app, I have this code. The above SQL query is a resource for the project.

```
static void RenderDefinition(int objectId, XmlElement parentElement)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(Resources.Commands.GetDefinition, connectionString))
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@object_Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = objectId;
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    var row = dt.Rows[0];

    // Create object element
    var e = parentElement.AppendChild(parentElement.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("definition")) as XmlElement;

    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        var value = row.ToXmlString(col);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) continue;

        if (col.ColumnName == "definition")
        {
            // The SQL code
            e.InnerText = value; // <-- Value is always DBNull, never the actual value
        }
        else
        {
            // Other defining attributes
            e.SetAttribute(col.ColumnName, value);
        }
    }
}
```

This generates the following XML:

```
<definition uses_ansi_nulls="true" uses_quoted_identifier="true" is_schema_bound="false" uses_database_collation="false" is_recompiled="false" null_on_null_input="false" uses_native_compilation="false"></definition>
```

I've tried the query as is. I've tried converting the definition column to a VARCHAR(MAX) and to a VARCHAR(8000).

Any thoughts?

Comment: `bigint` is not `int`...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for the catch, though it doesn't change the behavior as that was localized to SSMS.

Comment: When you debug, what returns from `dt.Rows.Count`?

Comment: What is the value of `Resources.Commands.GetDefinition`?

Comment: It's possible it's a permission issue, although can't know that for certain. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-modules-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Also if you only want current stored procedure definitions, I'd personally switch to using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES instead.

Comment: @ZoharPeled `dt.Rows.Count` returns 1, as expected, and all of the other columns populate.

Comment: @mjwills The value of `Resources.Commands.GetDefinition` is the SQL query included above, the contents of `GetDefinition.sql` file included as a string resource.

Comment: Perhaps it's the `ToXmlString` method that causes the problem. Try to use it only in the `else` part

Comment: @DaveBrown With regards to the permission idea, is it possible to partially fail a permissions check? I'll take a look at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`.

Comment: @DaveBrown Turns out `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` truncates the definition at 4,000 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that @DaveBrown had the right answer: It was a permissions issue, though it wasn't behaving in the way I thought it would.

I added LEN([definition]) to the query. The thought being that if it was problem in ADO.Net pulling down a 24,000 character sproc definition, I'd still get the character count of the definition. If it returned a NULL value, then it was something going on in SQL Server.

```
Select [definition], LEN([definition]) [definition_length], [uses_ansi_nulls], [uses_quoted_identifier], 
    [is_schema_bound], [uses_database_collation], [is_recompiled], 
    [null_on_null_input], [execute_as_principal_id], 
    [uses_native_compilation]
From [sys].[sql_modules]
Where [object_id] = @object_Id
```

When I stopped at a break point, `LEN([definition])` was null.

Turns out, someone who remain nameless to protect the guilty, does not have the same permissions in the environment we want to document as she has in the initial environment. The code works as written in one of the environments where I have authorial permissions for stored procedures and other other modules.

This ultimately comes down to an unexpected behavior due to permissions. I expected for SQL Server to raise an error when trying to query the definition rather than return null.

Answer (score 0):

try selecting from different sys table. E.g. :

```
SELECT DISTINCT SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id),o.name,c.[text]
FROM syscomments AS c
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON c.id = o.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE object_id = <your id>
```

another query that might help you:

```
SELECT so.[name],  m.[definition]
FROM sys.objects as so
inner join sys.sql_modules as m on m.object_id = so.object_id
WHERE so.[type] = 'P' AND so.object_id = <your id>;
```

here m.[definition] doesn't have length meaning it is as big as possible. In case it will return several rows for the same SP you will need to add another loop to your application and concatenate strings.

Let me know if it works

Comment: This didn't return the full text of the definition when running it in SSMS, pieces were missing.

Comment: it is possible that if procedure is big it will return two rows with beginning of SP and  end of SP ... check if it works in C# code

Comment: For my dev scenario, I'm using a big sproc, with more than 450 lines and over 24,000 characters, it's a monster. This query returns 7 records and just shy of 1,800 characters.